# Postgres добавить второе значение в строку

Tags: postgresql

Обновляю значение столбца таким образом:

```
UPDATE main_table SET value_act = 2 WHERE id = 1;
```

Нужно не обновить значение а добавить второе через запятую

Comment: А у него вообще есть массивы?

Comment: ну вот через django-multiselectfield можно внести в базу значения через запятую, интересует теперь апдейт в таком варианте

Comment: @Qwertiy в postgres есть массивы

Comment: @CaptainMountain а какого типа поле `value_act `?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский CharField

Comment: @CaptainMountain если подразумевается дальнейшая работа, как с массивом. Добавить 2 и получить 1, 2. Добавить 3 и получить 1, 2, 3. Убрать 2 из списка. То поле следует использовать []int.

Comment: @alexjust спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось добавить конкатенацию значений и в результате получилось "12"

```
UPDATE main_table SET value_act=value_act||2 WHERE id = 1;
```

Проблема остаётся актуальной, нужно получить значение "1,2"

Comment: `SET value_act=value_act || ',' || 2`

Answer (score 1):

```sql
UPDATE main_table 
   SET value_act = format('%s,%s', value_act, 2) 
 WHERE id = 1;
```